# After drag n drop sorting element create duplicasy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sorting, jquery-ui

I am creating the simple drag n drop with sorting but I am having a problem and that is after dragging and dropping the element when I sort them the the duplicasy of elements takes place and the second problem is with contenteditable it is not working properly when I right click then it works but when I left click it work sometime. What am I doing wrong. How can I solve it.

Comment: My jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/2/ I have taken it from codepen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `accept: '#textTemplate',` to `droppable` to let `#editorDesignView` accept drop just from `#textTemplate`

```
$(function(){

  $("#textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
      accept: '#textTemplate',      //add accept here
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).not('#editorDesignView div').appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
  var currentHtml = $("#editor").val();       
  $("#editor").val(currentHtml+html);
      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable();


});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#textTemplate").draggable({
    helper: "clone"
  });
  $( "#editorDesignView" ).droppable({
     accept: '#textTemplate',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var html = '<div id="" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p></div>';
  $(html).not('#editorDesignView div').appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
  var currentHtml = $("#editor").val();       
  $("#editor").val(currentHtml+html);
      }
    });
  $('#editorDesignView').sortable();
  

});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
#wrapper {width: 100%; height: 610px;}
#templateWrapper {width: 30%; height: 100%;float:left;overflow-y: scroll;}
#editorBlock {width: 70%; height: 100%;float:left;position: relative;background-color:#f1f1f1}
#editor{display:none;}

#editorDesignView {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="templateWrapper">
    <div id="textTemplate" class="template">
        <div>Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="editorBlock">
    <div id="editorDesignView"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```